# Optimize use of Streams

Tags: java, java-8, stream

```
boolean isRoleOld,isRoleNew;
for (Relations relation : listOfRelations)
    {
        if (Constants.ROLE_OLD.equalsIgnoreCase(relation.getRole()))
        {
            isRoleOld = true;
        }
        if (Constants.ROLE_NEW.equalsIgnoreCase(relation.getRole()))
        {
            isRoleNew = true;
        }
    }

    if (isRoleOld && isRoleNew)
    {
        “Success”
    }else{
        throw Exception();
    }
```

What i have done yet is

```
if (listOfRelations.stream()
.anyMatch(relation -> Constants.ROLE_OLD.equalsIgnoreCase(relation.getRole()))
          &&
          listOfRelations.stream()
                  .anyMatch(relation -> Constants.ROLE_NEW.equalsIgnoreCase(relation.getRole())))
  {
        System.out.println("Success");
}
```

How to use streams from Java8 to optimize this code. Using a anymatch twice is not the point.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does it work now?!

Comment: a trivial optimization could be adding an `else` after the 1st `if` block

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen code is already working but i want to modify it to streams

Comment: What specific problem are you having doing that?

Comment: @tgdavies i want to convert this code to be worked with the help of Streams.. it is working by using to streams with filter and anymatch but i want ted to know the optimized wat

Answer (score 0):

You could use a stream to `map` to each Role, and `filter` to identify old/new role match, then count the distinct matches.

```
long count = listOfRelations.stream().map(Relations::getRole)
        .filter(role -> Constants.ROLE_OLD.equalsIgnoreCase(role)
                     || Constants.ROLE_NEW.equalsIgnoreCase(role))
        .map(String::toLowerCase)
        .distinct().count();
if (count != 2) {
    throw new Exception();
}
System.out.println("Success");
```

However although this does only one pass through the stream it does not exit early once matched both roles so won't be ideal for large data-sets.

Comment: This only checks for one condition.

Comment: Yes, I see that I've overlooked the `&&` - will adjust answer later

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the solution with two `.anyMatch` checks is better because of short-circuiting when the required value is matched and therefore these checks may usually complete "sooner" than a full single run over the entire stream.  In case `ROLE_OLD` value is missing, `&&` short-circuiting occurs and no check for `ROLE_NEW` is executed.  The worst case is when `ROLE_OLD` is located at the end of the input `listOfRelations`, and no `ROLE_NEW` is there.

Similar loop-based solution would use `break` as soon as both `ROLE_OLD` and `ROLE_NEW` have been detected; in the worst case, the collection is fully iterated one time.